# Add active border to only a single item on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Clicking on an article I want to add a 'selected' border around it:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

const handleClick = (evt) => {
    setSelected(true)
  };


<article
   onClick={handleClick}
   className={`${selected ? "border-red-500" : ""} ... `}
>
```

This works great for a single article but how would I go about it if I had multiple articles? I only want to have one selected at a time. This method would obviously add a border around every article when clicked.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you added the code that showed how you list (and more importantly identify) multiple articles.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I have yet to write the code to do that, but I'm assuming I'd be retrieving from an api call then `map` each article. I'd have an `id` that i could add to each article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use multiple articles, You can use `map` to render and setSelected is id/index of `article`:

```
const handleClick = (id) => {
  setSelected(id !== selected ? id : "") 
};

listArticles.map((item, index) => (
  <article
   key = {item.id} // or index
   onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)} //or index
   className={`${selected === item.id ? "border-red-500" : ""} ... `} // or index
  >
))
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually looks something like this:

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

list.map((body, i) => <article key={i}
  onClick={() => setSelected(i)}
  className={`${selected == i ? "border-red-500" : ""} ... `}
  >{body}</article>)
```

But it depends a little on how you store, render, and identify your list of things (in this case articles).